# Using Number::Phone to validate and format

Tags: perl, unix, perl-module, libphonenumber

I'm trying to use [Number::Phone from CPAN](http://search.cpan.org/~dcantrell/Number-Phone/lib/Number/Phone.pm) to accomplish 2 tasks:

1. Validate a Phone Number; and
2. Format the number in E.164 Notation.

However, I'm unable to figure out how it works. My sample code is:

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use strict;
use warnings;
use Number::Phone;

foreach my $fnum ( '17888888', '97338888888', '00923455555333', '+97366767777' , '38383838') {
    my $phone = Number::Phone->new($fnum);
    my $norm = "";
    eval {
        $norm = $phone->format_using('E123'); # or 'Raw'
        print "E164 => '$norm'\n";
    } or do {
        print STDERR "Unable to parse '$fnum'\n";
    }
}
```

Expected output:

```sh
E164 => '+97317888888'
E164 => '+97338888888'
E164 => '+923455555333'
E164 => '+97366767777'
E164 => '+97338383838'
```

But the results were incorrect. I tried using [Number::Phone::Normalize](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Number-Phone-Normalize/lib/Number/Phone/Normalize.pm), but still not successful:

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use strict;
use warnings;
use Number::Phone::Normalize;

my %params = ( 
    'CountryCode'=>'973',
    'IntlPrefix' =>'00',
    'CountryCodeOut'=>'973',
    'IntlPrefixOut' => '+',
    );
my $nlz = Number::Phone::Normalize->new( %params );

foreach my $number ('17888888', '97338888888', '00923455555333', '+97366767777' , '38383838') {
    my $e164 = $nlz->intl( $number );
    print "E164 => '$e164'\n";
}
```

with the same expected output of:

```
E164 => '+97317888888'
E164 => '+97338888888'
E164 => '+923455555333'
E164 => '+97366767777'
E164 => '+97338383838'
```

However, this produced the wrong results too. The snippet Java code below works perfectly, and it's what I'm trying to achieve in Perl.

```java
// Uses libphonenumber: http://code.google.com/p/libphonenumber/
// setenv CLASSPATH .:libphonenumber-8.5.2.jar

// libphonenumber
import com.google.i18n.phonenumbers.PhoneNumberUtil;
import com.google.i18n.phonenumbers.Phonenumber.PhoneNumber;
import com.google.i18n.phonenumbers.NumberParseException;
import com.google.i18n.phonenumbers.PhoneNumberUtil.PhoneNumberFormat;

public class ValidateList {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            if (args.length != 1) {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid number of arguments.");
            }

            String file = args[0];
            PhoneNumberUtil phoneUtil = PhoneNumberUtil.getInstance();

            try (java.io.BufferedReader br = new java.io.BufferedReader(new java.io.FileReader(file))) {
                String line = null;
                while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {

                    try {
                        PhoneNumber phoneNumber = phoneUtil.parse(line, "BH");
                        boolean isValid = phoneUtil.isValidNumber(phoneNumber);
                        if (isValid) {
                            System.out.println( "E164 => " + phoneUtil.format(phoneNumber, PhoneNumberFormat.E164) );
                        }
                        else {
                            System.err.println( "Invalid => " + line);
                        }
                    } 
                    catch (NumberParseException e) {
                        System.err.println("NumberParseException for ("+line+"): " + e.toString());
                    }

                }
            }

        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println(e);
            System.err.println("Usage: java ValidateList <fileNameWithPhoneNumbers>");
        }
    }
}
```

```sh
% cat input.txt
17888888
97338888888
00923455555333
+97366767777
38383838

% javac -cp libphonenumber-8.5.2.jar ValidateList.java

% java -cp .:libphonenumber-8.5.2.jar ValidateList input.txt 
E164 => +97317888888
E164 => +97338888888
E164 => +923455555333
E164 => +97366767777
E164 => +97338383838
```

Your input is greatly appreciated.

Comment: What do you consider to be correct? Please provide your expected output and the current output. The Perl people around here likely don't know how to run your Java source, which isn't even an [mcve] and doesn't contain any numbers.

Comment: Thank you @simbabque I have edited my post to be more comprehensive.

Comment: And the Java people can't answer your question since it's about Perl. Don't tag it with "java" if the question is not *about* java - it's an irrelevant tag.

Comment: Thank you @ErwinBolwidt java tag has been removed.

Answer (score 1):

When I run the first example code for the numbers, two of those fail to be parsed:

17888888 - this is obvious, when calling Number::Phone without a country code, this will not be parsed as it's unclear what country this is from

00923455555333 - 923 is, according to a quick google search, the country code for Pakistan. The Wikipedia page for dialing codes in Pakistan shows no 455, leading me to think that this is not a known area code to either Number::Phone or Wikipedia. I suspect it is an invalid number.

So for the first Number: specify which country this is supposed to be from.

If you are certain the other number is correct, you know more about that than the developer of Number::Phone currently and I'm sure he'd be happy to receive your input in the form of a more complete Number::Phone localized package.

The fact that your Java code accepts the (probably) invalid number does not necessarily mean it is more correct, just that it is less picky in what it declares to be a correct number.

Edit:

Asking Phone::Number to parse the input '+923455555333' instead of '00923455555333' leads to the desired output.

Looking at the source of Phone::Number:

```
# ... processing input arguments
$number = "+$number" unless($number =~ /^\+/);
```

It becomes clear that the 00 is interpreted as '+00' and then rejected as being an invalid number.
[View some discussion on that here](https://github.com/DrHyde/perl-modules-Number-Phone/issues/39)

It seems to me you will have to handle this yourself.
One way may be to simply replace leading 00 with '+' - preferably only if parsing failed.

The other number can be parsed if you make it clear what country it should belong to.

Perhaps like so:

```
my $phone = Number::Phone->new($fnum);
unless ($phone){
    $phone = Number::Phone->new('BH',$fnum);
    if ( !$phone && $fnum =~ s/^00/+/ ){
        # You should probably check the discussion I linked.
        # There may well be problems with this approach!
        $phone = Number::Phone->new($fnum);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you @bytepusher for your response. Both numbers are valid. I'm expected to use a "Default Country" which I haven't figured out how to do in Number::Phone. See (libphonenumber JavaScript Demo) `https://rawgit.com/googlei18n/libphonenumber/master/javascript/i18n/phonenumbers/demo-compiled.html`. For the "Default Country" use `BH`. All the numbers I've supplied should be valid, and I expect them in E.164 format as shown in my expected output.

Comment: I'm not sure where this "Default Country" is coming from - I do not see it mentioned in the Documentation.

Comment: I put in a suggestion how you might approach this, after now having discovered what the actual problem is. Good luck!